# dnsmasq: specific domain and subdomain to specific folders

Tags: networking, linux-networking, dnsmasq, raspbian

I'm creating a website on my Raspi 3 and I want to link domains with the html folder to make it easier to access in the local network.

I want to achieve the following:

mydomain.example -> 192.168.0.1/mydomain/

test.mydomain.example -> 192.168.0.1/mydomain/test

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should set up different *virtualhosts* in the webserver of your rasp. From the details, I suggest to ask more on the sister-site https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. `dnsmasq` is a caching domain name forwarder/resolver not a HTTP server. But you can do this with any HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any example how to do so?

Comment: Visit https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/TutorialConfiguration and scroll down to "10 minutes". You can have multiple `$HTTP["host"]` entries all pointing to different document roots. This is for lighty but you can find similar examples for any HTTP server of your choice.